# cant figure out how to fix the bug

Tags: java, arrays, radix-sort

Using JAVA I am trying to sort and array of integers (ascending) by radix sort but dont seem to work out the bug.

```
public class Ex_radix {
    public static void radixSort(int[] A) {
        int d = 0;
        for (int digit = 0; digit < A.length; digit++) {// Checks what is the
                                                        // maximum amount of
                                                    // digits in any number
        int num = A[digit];
        int counter = 0;
        while (num != 0) {
            num = num / 10;
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        if (counter > d) {
            d = counter;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("this is the max number of digits: " + d);
    int[] B = new int[A.length];// Copying the array
    for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
        B[j] = A[j];
        System.out.println("this is cell " + j + ": " + B[j]);
    }
    int iteration = 1;//Starting sort
    while (iteration <= d) {
        for (int i = 1; i < B.length; i++) {
            if (B[i] % (10 ^ iteration) < B[i - 1] % (10 ^ iteration)) {
                int temp = A[i - 1];
                B[i - 1] = B[i];
                B[i] = temp;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {// Checking
            System.out.print(B[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        iteration = iteration + 1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] C = { 329, 457, 657, 839, 436, 720, 355 };
    radixSort(C);
}
}
```

if you run it you see it starts fine but within the first iteration and the next ones numbers gets copied.
I tried several methods but coudlnt figure it out.

first iteratiom: 457, 657, 839, 436, 839, 355, 720, 
second iteration: 457, 657, 436, 657, 355, 720, 720, 
third iteration: 657, 436, 657, 657, 720, 720, 720,

Comment: `^` is not exponentiation.  You could use `Math.pow`, but I'd keep another variable `powerOf10` that holds "10 to the _iteration_ power".  Then when you add 1 to `iteration`, I'll bet you can guess what to do with `powerOf10`.

Comment: right. i fixed that, stupid of me. but it still does not solve the problem. im still getting coppied numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the duplication is this:

```
 int temp = A[i - 1];
 B[i - 1] = B[i];
 B[i] = temp;
```

You're getting temp from A and setting it to B.  This will stop the duplication, but it won't fix your sort.  Radix sort uses buckets to determine sort order (that's the reason for the 2nd array), there's no comparing with each other.  You're doing a kind of modified swap.